# Why do I get a connection failed message on login? (OS X)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, home-networking

Any idea why I get one (or more, as shown here) instances of this message after login, or sometimes when launching an application?
[image: Connection Failed. There was an error connecting to the server “Soyuz”.]

(Soyuz is the name of another computer on my home network. This message occurs whether or not I am at home. I can also manually connect to Soyuz, no problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like OS X is trying to connect to a drive which is unreachable.

This can happen when an app is trying to open a file stored on the remote "Soyuz" server. Check for obsolete apps in the following preference panel:

```
System Preferences > Accounts > Login Items
```

Comment: I think you’ve nailed it!